# How to make request to custom URL using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I make a request to e.g. `/videos/:id/related?` using Ember Data and RESTAdapter to fetch objects of `video` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DS.RESTAdapter. It does exactly what you want. Check out these links:

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

EDIT:
Try using the findHasMany hook
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany

Comment: Thanks. I am using DS.RESTAdapter and I know how to make request for a collection (e.g. `find('video', {page: 2})` - `/videos?page=2`) and individual objects (e.g. `find('video', 1)` - `/videos/1`). I don't know to make request to `/videos/2/whatever`.

Comment: I've just added info about RESTAdapter to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work? Do I have to make self referenced `hasMany` association named `related` in `Video` model and return `links: {related: '/videos/1/related'}` in JSON response from the server?

Comment: To make it work one needs to add `links: {related: '/videos/1/related'}` to JSON response, then add relationship `related: DS.hasMany('video', { async: true })` to the model and then one can make request by calling `video.get('related')`. Simple :)